How do I make the text start from right to left in QToolButton, and how do I remove the space between the icon and the text?
As shown in the image, I created 3 qtoolbutton and made the following settings:
minimumSize=200px
In this case I tried to get rid of the space between icon and text by padding-left and padding-right but both of them increase the size of the button

[In the second image I did not fixed the size of qtoolbuttons, there was a small space and I got rid of it using the following settings:
padding-left = -8
paddign-right = 0
But as shown in the image the qtoolbuttons are not the same size and when I try to make them the same size I get a space between the text and the icon

In the third image, the shape I want appears
The icons are on the right and the text is on the left, and I achieved this with layoutDirection = RightToLeft
The text starts from right to left I achieved this in image 2 , but the buttons are different in size
The buttons are  equal in size I achieved this in image 1 , but there is a space between the icon and the text


This can't be achieved in Designer only, it has to be done by code, with a proper subclass. Why are you using QToolButton? How did you get to have the icon on the right edge? You mention having to explicitly set the layout direction in the third case, but seeing the text you're using, that should be the default on your system. I also don't understand what is the problem in the third image (there must be space between text and icon). For future reference, note that you should limit images to show display results, not to also include captions that are fundamental to understand the problem.

If I change the texts in the third image, I will get the second image.

Please address everything written/asked in my comment.


I use Qt Designer along with code when I need more customization.
I use QToolButton because I'm using the PyQt library, and the same issue applies to QPushButton.
I place the icons on the right edge using layoutDirection.
If the text takes the default direction based on the text used, as you say, then why am I facing this issue here? It’s not the case because the icons are aligned to the far right while the text is aligned to the far left.



We know that you're using PyQt, but, while similar, QPushButton and QToolButton are not the same, and you should choose them with awareness; specifically, QPushButton supports the text-align QSS property, QToolButton doesn't; 3. the layoutDirection should only change the direction, not the absolute horizontal alignment (that's why I specified the right edge: setting the direction should still show icon and text in the center), which makes me think that you may be setting other properties in the QSS you're not reporting, therefore we need a proper [mre]; 4. alignment values »


» are usually inverted when using RightToLeft, meaning that things like AlignLeft will result in being aligned on the right (see the Qt::Alignment docs, specifically the note for the AlignAbsolute enum. I seem to remember a Qt bug report about a similar issue, but I cannot really find it right now (I'll try again later). In the meantime, I suggest you to [edit] your question, provide a basic [mre] with a minimal UI having all unnecessary properties left as default (not set) as long as they do not affect reproducibility, and a related »

» code if relevant; please ensure that what you provide is both minimal and reproducible, we should be able to easily copy, paste and run what you give us (and then reproduce the issue) without any substantial modification. It's also very important to include all relevant environment info: detailed OS and Qt (not PyQt) versions, default layout direction for the current OS and for Qt (QApplication.layoutDirection()), and the output of QApplication.style().objectName() (after creating its instance).
